# extjs how to create menu with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, extjs, menu

I am able to create menu with check boxes as follows

```
xtype : 'button',
id : 'resultExportBtn',
ui : 'custombtn',
cls : 'field-margin',
style : 'margin-right:5px',
text : 'Export',
menu : [ 
    {
        text : 'CSV',
        fName : 'csv',
        checked : true,
        xtype : 'menucheckitem'
    }, {
        text : 'PDF',
        fName : 'pdf',
        checked : false,
        xtype : 'menucheckitem'
    }
]
```

Anyone knows how to create menu with radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use radiogroup xtype instead menucheckitem

```
menu : [ 
    {
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        columns: 1,
        vertical: true,
        items: [
            { 
                boxLabel: 'CSV', 
                name: 'rb', 
                inputValue: '1' 
            },
            { 
                boxLabel: 'PDF', 
                name: 'rb', 
                inputValue: '2' 
            }           
        ]
    }
]
```

---

### [Look example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/a5g)